# Changing iOS Deployment Target causes storyboard localization to stop working

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

In Xcode 6, if I set my iOS Deployment Target to 8.0, the storyboard is localised. If I change the target to 7.0 or 7.1, it doesn't. The weird thing is other localised strings (like Localisable.strings) works fine. Only the storyboard doesn't get translated.

I've tried cleaning the project (Product > Clean) but it still doesn't work.

Any suggestions on getting it to work?

Here is a sample project that's not working for me: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5651432/Dude.zip

EDIT: another interesting fact this only happens if the app is a universal app. If I switch to iPhone or iPad, it works.

Comment: do a clean build using option+alt+shift+K

Comment: did it, nothing. Still the same, if target 8.0 ok, else fail.

Comment: I updated to Xcode 6.1 today and everything is working now.

Comment: ok, thnx for your share....